# How to be not confused about a channel direction in Go?

Tags: go, concurrency, channel

I'm a newbie in Go, so sorry if my question seems stupid.

I have a really hard time to get the channel syntax and vocabulary in Golang, especially when it's about direction.

When I read that `c chan<- int` is a "send-only" channel, I understand that this channel can only send data. But it seems to be the contrary, and that we can only put stuff into this chan.

Same thing for the "receive-only" channel `c <-chan int` : for me it's a channel that can only receive data, but it seems this kind of channel can only send data and not receive some.

See, I'm really confused, so if you have a better way to explain it, or a good mnemonic way to understand it, I'll thank you for the rest of my days!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *channel* cannot send nor receive data. *You* can send data *on* the channel, and you can receive data *from* the channel. And then the direction is exactly what its name says.

Also note that the "arrow" visualizes the direction. If it points toward the channel (toward the `chan`) like `c chan<- int`, it's a send-only. If it points away from the channel (outward of the `chan`) like `c <-chan int`, it's a receive-only.

Same goes for actually sending anything on it ([Send statement](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Send_statements)) like `c <- 1`, or receiving something from it ([Receive operator](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Receive_operator)) like `a = <-c`.

Comment: ok, so "send-only" and "receive-only" describes the action I can do with the channel, and not the actions the channel can do. I got it now. Thank you so much !

Comment: Technically speaking you could create "send-only" or "receive-only" channel. But I have never seen a reasonable using. Each channel have two ends, and make sense every time use both. However when you see `func() <- chan int` and can decode it, you will understand - I could receive from returned channel. And when you see `func() chan <- int` you know - your are responsible for sending data to channel and close it at proper time. Of course - the same for variable `var c <- chan int` vs `var c chan <- int`.

Comment: @lofcek actually you can't create a send-only or receive-only channel, that would make no sense. You *can* have a send-only or receieve-only *reference* to a channel, so that you can declare at compile time which reference is the sender and which is the receiver; which makes the point of it pretty clear: it's not that the channel only has senders or only has receivers, it's just that it's clear which is which.

Comment: @Adrian - you could do it .. Compiler allows you to write `ro := make(<-chan int)` or `so := make(chan <-int)`. But as I have already told - you take no advantage of such channels.

Comment: The only use I can see for such a channel would be an interminable block (same as `select{}`.